# Reading < 8 bits from a reader in Golang

Tags: go

While handling raw IP packages in Golang I've came across a problem which I cannot seem to find a solution for:

The [IPv4 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791) contains fields which are smaller than 8 bits. For example the Version or the Header Length (4 bits each) or the Flags (3 bits).

How do I read those values from an io.Reader and handle them using Golang afterwards? I've been using the [binary.Read](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read) method so far, however since the smallest integer type in Golang is an int8, that is not possible in this case.

Comment: You can read a byte at once and then use a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) to extract specific fields.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`io.Reader` can only read bytes, not bits. What you can do is read the bytes and extract the bits yourself:

```
var (
    byte0 byte = 0xAF
    byte5 byte = 0x89
)

version := byte0 >> 4
headerLength := byte0 & 0x0F
flags := byte5 >> 5
```

Of course, another approach is to write a `BitReader` type, which could of course be more efficient but you get the idea: http://play.golang.org/p/Wyr_K9YAro :)