# Compare bits in two arrays

Tags: go

I've got stuck with ex4.1 for the book which says: 
*Write a function that counts the number of bits that are different in two SHA256 hashes.*

The partial solution I came up with is pasted below, but it's wrong - it counts number of different bytes not bits.
Could you please point me in the right direction?

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
)

var s1 string = "unodostresquatro"
var s2 string = "UNODOSTRESQUATRO"
var h1 = sha256.Sum256([]byte(s1))
var h2 = sha256.Sum256([]byte(s2))

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("s1: %s h1: %X h1 type: %T\n", s1, h1, h1) 
    fmt.Printf("s2: %s h2: %X h2 type: %T\n", s2, h2, h2) 
    fmt.Printf("Number of different bits: %d\n", 8 * DifferentBits(h1, h2))
}

func DifferentBits(c1 [32]uint8, c2 [32]uint8) int {
    var counter int 
    for x := range c1 {
        if c1[x] != c2[x] {
            counter += 1
        }
    }   
    return counter

}
```

Comment: You already have the number in bits: 8 * the byte count. It would be very, very odd to have to read bit-by-bit in Go (or any other non-embedded language). Are you sure the book (which book?) wants you to do that? Else, see this existing answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29583024/reading-8-bits-from-a-reader-in-golang - but I can honestly say you should never have to do that when comparing hashes in a real program.

Comment: What you're implementing is called Hamming Distance, and is a very common and useful algorithm. You should read about bit-wise operations on bytes and the solution isn't hard - XOR the two bytes to get a byte with only the different bits set. Then count the bits with bit shifting.

Comment: @peterSO I don't doubt the OP: there may have, however, been context surrounding the question that wasn't made available in their post. If the book does want you to perform bit-wise operations, would not a previous exercise or chapter provide some introduction before throwing you in? (it's not even clear which book is being discussed; I assume it's GoPL).

Comment: @peterSO I know what Hamming weight is :) Again, with only the question (and no surrounding text!), would you immediately presume to operate in bits (the less straightforward approach)? If you had already read the book, sure, but for those of us that haven't we're left guessing.

Comment: (the Go std. lib, for example, only counts the bytes of a hash, not the bits, because in many cases it's unnecessary to do so)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language](http://www.gopl.io/)
>
> Alan A. A. Donovan · Brian W.Kernighan
>
> Exercise 4.1: Write a function that counts the number of bits that
>   are different in two SHA256 hashes.

---

> [The C Programming Language](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/C-Programming-Language/9780131103627.page)
>
> Brian W.Kernighan · Dennis M. Ritchie
>
> Exercise 2-9. In a two's complement number system, `x &= (x-1)` deletes
>   the rightmost 1-bit in `x`. Use this observation to write a faster
>   version of `bitcount`.

---

> [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html)
>
> Sean Eron Anderson
>
> [Counting bits set, Brian Kernighan's way](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetKernighan)
>
> ```
> unsigned int v; // count the number of bits set in v
> unsigned int c; // c accumulates the total bits set in v
> for (c = 0; v; c++)
> {
>   v &= v - 1; // clear the least significant bit set
> }
> ```

---

For exercise 4.1, you are counting the number of **bytes** that are different. Count the number of **bits** that are different. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
)

func BitsDifference(h1, h2 *[sha256.Size]byte) int {
    n := 0
    for i := range h1 {
        for b := h1[i] ^ h2[i]; b != 0; b &= b - 1 {
            n++
        }
    }
    return n
}

func main() {
    s1 := "unodostresquatro"
    s2 := "UNODOSTRESQUATRO"
    h1 := sha256.Sum256([]byte(s1))
    h2 := sha256.Sum256([]byte(s2))
    fmt.Println(BitsDifference(&h1, &h2))
}
```

Output:

```
139
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
)

var (
    s1 string = "unodostresquatro"
    s2 string = "UNODOSTRESQUATRO"
    h1        = sha256.Sum256([]byte(s1))
    h2        = sha256.Sum256([]byte(s2))
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("s1: %s h1: %X h1 type: %T\n", s1, h1, h1)
    fmt.Printf("s2: %s h2: %X h2 type: %T\n", s2, h2, h2)
    fmt.Printf("Number of different bits: %d\n", DifferentBits(h1, h2))
}

// bitCount counts the number of bits set in x
func bitCount(x uint8) int {
    count := 0
    for x != 0 {
        x &= x - 1
        count++
    }
    return count
}

func DifferentBits(c1 [32]uint8, c2 [32]uint8) int {
    var counter int
    for x := range c1 {
        counter += bitCount(c1[x] ^ c2[x])
    }
    return counter
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xq1BW1pH_H)